# How to set UIImageView height different sizes for different devices in UITableViewCell?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

So currently I have a UITableView cell and i have some buttons, labels and a UIImageView, the height is set at 400 which is constant.

The only thing is, when running on smaller devices like a iPhone 4 and 5/SE the gap(background) above and below the image is greater.

I know i need to set the height like so:

```
6 Plus - 386

6 - 347

4/5/SE - 292
```

How can i achieve this in storyboard if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this in storyboard, you'll need to learn using [AutoLayout](https://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2). If you don't want to learn it, you can hard-code your sizes programmatically (not recommanded) with some conditionals, here's how to do.

First, add those macros to your code :

```
#define IS_IPAD (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
#define IS_IPHONE (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
#define IS_RETINA ([[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] >= 2.0)

#define SCREEN_WIDTH ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width)
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)
#define SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH (MAX(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
#define SCREEN_MIN_LENGTH (MIN(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))

#define IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH < 568.0)
#define IS_IPHONE_5 (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 568.0)
#define IS_IPHONE_6 (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 667.0)
#define IS_IPHONE_6P (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 736.0)
```

Then, use it like that :

```
if (IS_IPHONE_5 || IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS) {
    //size is 292
} else if (IS_IPHONE_6) {
    //size is 347
} else if (IS_IPHONE_6P) {
    //size is 386
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I actually already have autolayout set up, and i was thinking instead of hardcoding the imageView height, ill just use a condition like what you suggested inside `heightForRowAtIndex`. What do you think?

Comment: Indeed, if you already have correctly setted up autolayout, setting `heightForRowAtIndex` with condition should work properly :)

Comment: how would i add the if statement. having trouble figuring out how i should do it. because technically with the if statement it will reach a non-void function

Comment: Just add your last return OUTSIDE of the if statement. If none of the previous IF were true, it will return the last value. Or, add a line `return 0;` (for example) after your if statement.